# Wrong HTML report when using -i option in cppcheck

Tags: html, cppcheck

I work for a middleware company. We would like to integrate Cppcheck into our build system to help preventing errors and issues in our code. Our code is big, and it's distributed in several modules (each module in a different folder). These modules have many dependencies between them.

When running Cppcheck, we want to run it only once over the whole code to give the whole view to the tool. However, some modules are not related to the core ones, and we want to skip those modules from the analysis. Besides, we have implemented APIs for different languages. So for example, we have some modules for C++ that we would like to analyze separately from the C modules.

We have basically two options:

1. call Cppcheck with a list of the modules that we want to analyze, or
2. call Cppcheck from the top level folder of the code, and use `-i` options to ignore all the modules that shouldn't be analyzed.

Both approaches worked fine up to the point of creating the XML report. The problem appears when calling `cppcheck-htmlreport`. We observed that no index.html or stats.html were generated. Besides, only some of the results appearing in the XML were translated into HTML reports. For many results, the HTML pages were not generated.

Any memory problem can be discarded. We already verified this. Besides, the tool doesn't start creating HTML reports from the XML results consecutively and then it stops. Actually, what happens is that the HTML reports go jumping. I mean, the HTML report for error number 1 in the XML is created, then maybe next one is number 5, and so on.

We called `cppcheck-htmlreport` with `--source-code` option pointing to the top level folder of the code. I think the problem may be caused by this. I tried to call Cppcheck just from the top level folder, with no `-i` options, and then the HTML reports were generated without issues. So it looks like the XML created by using `-i` options cannot be correctly understood by `cppcheck-htmlreport`.
Is there a way to provide `-i` options to `cppcheck-htmlreport` as well? I think this could solve the problem...

I have also noticed that the problem only seems to appear when many modules and code is analyzed. When analyzing only a few modules the HTML report was correct, although we still called `cppcheck-htmlreport` providing the top level folder as `--source-dir`.

Is this a known issue in Cppcheck HTML generator? Is there any way to solve this?
Any advice is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Sonia

Comment: which version did you use? also, try http://trac.cppcheck.net/report/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I use version 1.69. I solved the problem anyway. Finally we got an error from the cppcheck-htmlreport:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)

This error shows that cppcheck-htmlreport is having issues to encode non-ascii characters (>128). Tool is written in Python, so I just modified the code of the tool to avoid printing these non-ascii characters (I didn't need them in my case).